# Which one is the correspoding eigenvector? Rows or columns

Tags: python, pandas, math

Suppose I have following array. Are the rows or columns corresponding eigenvectors for eigenvalues. Sorry for easy and dumb question. But I just want to be absolutely certain.

```
import numpy as np

A = [45,37,42,35,39]
B = [38,31,26,28,33]
C = [10,15,17,21,12]

arrays= np.array([A,B,C])

covMatrix = np.cov(arrays,bias=True)print (covMatrix)

# Finding eigvenvalue and eigenvector

eigval, eigvec = np.linalg.eig(covMatrix)eigval = eigval.realprint(eigval,"\n", eigvec)
```

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html In your case 'eigvec' is the eigenVector, but see the ref for details.

Comment: Yeah I know eigenvec is the eigenvector. 
My question is whether rows or columns are the corresponding eigenvectors to the eigenvalues.

Comment: Nature of the eigenvectors is not obvious. There are number of tutorials. For instance this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OELTJdaU8aA

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

```
The normalized (unit “length”) eigenvectors, such that the column v[:,i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i].
```